# Incrementing Counters in Azure Table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I plan to use Azure Tables to store various application related counters. My concerns are the counters are incremented from many different client instances of the application.

Seems like a simple task at the surface, but looking at it closer it is quite challenging.

I hoping someone can share some wisdom that will help make the problem more manageable.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give more information about the purpose of your counters ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11853335/67824

Answer (score 4):

Steve Marx has covered this quite well in his [blog](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/architecting-scalable-counters-with-windows-azure) and the related [Cloud Cover episode](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-43-Scalable-Counters-with-Windows-Azure).  The short version is:

- The client contacts the web role.
- The web role updates a static variable using the `System.Threading.Interlocked` functionality.  This avoids multiple threads on the server trying to update the same number.
- Each webrole has a background thread which on a timed basis writes back to the count table which includes as part of its PartitionKey/RowKey the instance name.  This avoids two instances trying to update the same number at the same time.

Comment: Would this work for multiple web roles?

Comment: Yes, because each instance of each role will have a unique name and therefore have its own row in the underlying table.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of keeping a counter why don't you store one row per hit. Aggregate the data to know the counter value.

Hybrid approach would be keep collating hits. Keep performing aggregates and saving. Old hit data then be cleared\deleted.

Answer (score 3):

With Redis Cache introduction Redis can be used for this task as well as redis has atomic increment (http://redis.io/commands/INCR).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of counters and the frequency of update, Azure table storage may not be the best way to go. For one, table storage does not provide for locking or transaction support or the ability to update a value on the server without first retrieving it. So, you may end up which a situation where your update fails because another instance updated the row while you attempted to update the same row.

If volume and frequency of updates makes  frequent retrying updates unpalatable, you may want to consider SQL Azure instead where updates can be made atomic on the server side. (something like UPDATE Abc  SET Value = Value + 1 WHERE ….).